# Compatibility of Axis2 with older wsdl files / Web Services

Tags: web-services, apache-axis, axis

If I understand correctly, all frameworks use SOAP while communicating with Web Services. I am still in dilemma whether a particular server supports all frameworks.

Let's say, XYZ has released its WSDL file longback (in Axis era), and they have not upgraded anything. Now, can I use **Axis2** to build the stubs from the same WSDL, and communicate successfully with the same old server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different versions of WSDL and SOAP, AXIS2 would normally use SOAP 1.2 This is a [reference](http://www.keith-chapman.org/2009/02/axis2-how-to-set-soap-version-on-client.html) to how to use SOAP 1.1 with Axis2.

Comment: Thanks, so there is no chance of a failure if we take some precautions.